# How to disable graphical effects in a ubuntu 16.04 server (for ssh X tunelling)

Tags: server, ssh, xorg, openbox

I have an ubuntu server where I installed xauth, xorg and openbox in order to access individual graphical applications from remote using ssh tunelling, e.g.

`ssh -XC user@server.org qgis`

How can I disable effects like fading menus on the server in order to further improve speed ?

(PS: I am not 100% sure I am running openbox behind the scene)